# How to navigate to angular2 default route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have declared a route as default using `useAsDefault: true`.  I now want to use this route without its name (its for a reusable component).  Example:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']">Go to default route</a>
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

Is this possible? I had a quick look at the router source but could not even find a way to query the default route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: No, it's not possible at this time.

But if you really need, it can be hacked like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(_route:RouteRegistry) {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      // it will print default route's name
      console.log(this._capitalize(_route._rules.values().next().value.defaultRule.hash))}, 
    500);
  }

  private _capitalize(str:string){
    if (!str) return "";
    return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1, str.length);
  }
}
```